# Biostar TA970XE motherboard, mysterious VGA error

Tags: motherboard, vga

It won't boot, during POST it makes 8 beeps, which means "VGA error" according to the booklet. The graphics card is a GeForce 560 which works fine in another computer. I tried the GeForce 9600 from that other computer, won't work either with this motherboard.

I sent the motherboard back to the seller for a replacement, got the replacement, I get the exact same error.

I know the graphics cards are fine. I checked the extra power connectors that go to the cards, they do receive power. I reseated the cards, tried the other PCI Express connector, same result.

I'm not sure what else I could try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm, sorry. Everything started to work after I changed the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

did you ask that RMA center about your previous Mobo issue? Are you sure about replace or that's your old Mobo?
does your graphic card need extra power? did you test in both situation? plugged or not plugged?
sorry about that, but did you reset bios when there is no power?

Comment: Post your questions(!) as comments, not as an answer. http://superuser.com/faq#deletion